# Running a CronJob of a .js File Does Not Output Console to .txt or .log file

Tags: javascript, cron, console, console.log

I have a cronjob task to run a .js script.

The cronjob does run the task well when directed the output to its custom .txt file.

I would like to customize into 2 sets of console outputs for one as normal user/engineers and one for the developer to debug.

However, the following .txt file(s) gets created only when I run `node main.js` file in the CLI console instead of the cronjob running the `main.js` and getting the .txt files.

**cronjob.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/node /home/files/main.js
```

**`crontab -l`**

`*/10 * * * * /home/files/cronjob.sh >> /home/files/cronjob_log.txt 2>&1`

**main.js**

```
const normalUserConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream(outputNormalUser.txt));

const developerConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream(outputDeveloper.txt));

normalUserConsole.log("Timestamp: " + getDateString() + ' hrs');
```

- *The `getDateString()` does able to get an output.*

Is there any way to get cronjob to run the console.log and getting the output to the respective .txt files?

Comment: In your cronjob.sh should you not be calling the node to run the main.js?

Comment: my apologies for the typo there. I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should modify cronjob.sh to log the output of the program there.

So it should be

`#!/bin/sh /usr/bin/node /home/files/main.js >> /home/files/cronjob_log.txt`